# SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 101033 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) fix?

Tags: javascript, json, git

So I am trying to complete the open source mission in TwilioQuest but I can't becuase the terminal gives me an error when I run this command:

```
git commit -m "feat(pixels): add my new pixel"
```

It tells me there is an error in one of the scripts which is this one and its written in Javascript:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const { sortPixels, pixelsToString } = require('../utils/pixels-helper');

const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);
const writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);

const pixelFilePath = path.join('_data', 'pixels.json');

readFile(pixelFilePath, { encoding: 'utf8' })
  .then(pixelFileData => {
    const pixels = JSON.parse(pixelFileData);

    const sortedPixelString = pixelsToString(sortPixels(pixels));

    writeFile(pixelFilePath, sortedPixelString);
  })
  .catch(console.log);
```

The error it gives me for this script is this:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 101033
      at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

       8 |   const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../_data/', dataJsonFile);
       9 |   const pixelJsonString = await readFile(filePath, 'utf8');
    > 10 |   return JSON.parse(pixelJsonString);
         |               ^
      11 | }
      12 |
      13 | describe('pixels', () => {
```

What is this error about and how can I fix it?

Comment: The error is not in the script, but in the JSON.

Comment: oh, well the whole folder has a bunch of JSON files. How do I know which one has the error?

Comment: what is `fillePath` in the error - is that your code? you'll need to add some debugging, perhaps use try/catch in your code

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `git` features in this matter : this error is triggered by a custom script, most probably `.git/hooks/pre-commit`.

You may open `.git/hooks/pre-commit` in an editor to view how your code is tested, and execute in your terminal `.git/hooks/pre-commit` to see if the test passes or fails.

---

Regarding javascript debugging : use your regular tools and methods to debug.

For example :

- you may add `console.log(filePath)` before calling `JSON.parse`, to see which file was opened, or `console.log(pixelJsonString)` to see what is returned from your function,
- you may use a node debugger to follow you program's execution
  ...